# Anchor tags in android "WebKit" browser

Tags: android, webview, webkit, anchor

If i open:
content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/vik_book_temp/oebps/ch01.htm
in an android browser the same opens correctly, but when I open a anchor tag page like 
content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/vik_book_temp/oebps/ch01.htm#s01c02 
the android browser fails to open the relevant section within the html page. 
Whereas
content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/vik_book_temp/oebps/ch01.htm?s01c02 opens the top of the html page. Is this is a bug in the android browser or incompatibility issue with anchor tags in android browser. If  yes then what is a way around? How do I set anchor tags or change the "#" symbol to what symbol at runtime to enable navigation to a section?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542702/basic-internal-links-dont-work-in-honeycomb-app/7297536#7297536)