# Android's WebView can't go back in local assets

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with WebView. My app has build in help files made with html in local assets. And I show html file with WebView.

My problem is, WebView's goBack() function can't go back to previous page when it tries to return to bookmarked position.

For example:

- Page1 has link to bookmark1 in Page1.
- And Page1 has link to Page2.
- Showing Page1 and hit link to Page2, then goBack() can go back to Page1. Fine.
- Showing Page1 and hit link to bookmark1, and then hit link to Page2, then goBack() can't go back to page1. WebView shows error like it can't find url with #bookmark1.

I suspect WebView is not handing viewing history for local files. I'm using OS 4.0.3.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a (compromising) solution for this issue. This issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542702/basic-internal-links-dont-work-in-honeycomb-app) and one solution can be found [here](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/mydq/20121130/p1) (Japanese page, sorry). In my case, after knowing it's a bug in some range of Android OS, going back to previous page (not to exact anchor position) is fine. So I ended up with next code.

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542702/basic-internal-links-dont-work-in-honeycomb-app
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        String url = failingUrl;
        int index = url.indexOf("#");
        if (index != -1)
        {
            url = url.substring(0, index);
        }
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
});
```

With this code when it can't go back to previous page with anchor, it goes back to previous page without anchor. I compromised with it. I tried to make it better with other solutions using Java Script but did not work.